# Waxom (or other) Tablet API for capturing signature image

Tags: windows, tablet, wacom

I need to capture a signature in my application as an image (GIF/TIFF,..whatever). Does anyone knows a good API for doing this (COM/ActiveX is preffered). I've read about Wintab, but it looks obsolete...

Does reasent  version of windows includes a standard API for doing this?

Thanks,
  Matra

Answer (score 0):

you can use SigniShell or SigPlus
http://www.topazsystems.com/